# How to create a "variable" group (for future reference via \n) in extended grep regex type (how not to repeat myself)?

Tags: regex, grep, find

Result: I wanted from regex what it is not intended for. If you don’t find a function in regex, then most likely it’s not there. Regex for simple cases

Note: I want the solution to work even if instead of `lr` and `h` there could be `(huge regex expression)` and `(another huge regexp)` respectively. Solutions that don't help me avoid repeating myself in such cases don't interest me

Let's say I have files produced by the following command:

```
touch {,lr,lrlr,lrlrlr}h{,lr,lrlr,lrlrlr}
```

Files:

```
h
lrh
lrlrh
lrlrlrh
hlr
lrhlr
lrlrhlr
lrlrlrhlr
```

and so on

How can I find such files via find and regextype egrep command as per the terms of the question?

The problem is that I can't declare a group without it affecting the regexp: `\./(lr)\1*h\1*`. This won't find the files: `h` `hlr` and so on

I tried `(lr)|\./\1*h\1*` and `\./(lr)?\1*h\1*` and they don't work for the same reason

I don’t want to repeat myself in my regexp. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong way to do this either in the wrong regex type or in general I want from regex something that it cannot give. If this is so, then correct my way, or recommend another regex type, please. And if there is no regex type that suits me, then I would like to find a library for *rust* that I could modify to make a regex engine, or a library that does not need to be modified, ideally. It just seems to me that it will be very difficult to write a regex engine from scratch

Comment: You said you want a solution for `regextype egrep` (i.e. works with EREs) but accepted an answer that requires a PCRE and so won't work with an ERE. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: It's always far easier to write code that will match the strings you want than to not match similar strings you do not want (e.g. `.*` will match every string you listed but it's probably not the right solution) so you should include some similar strings that should not match in your sample input/output.

Comment: Keep in mind ['Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.'](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) so a single regexp may not be the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RegEx to find those strings is `^(lr){0,3}h(lr){0,3}$`. This is interpreted as:

```
^            Start of string
(?:lr)       The two characters, in a non-capturing group
{0,3}        ... with zero to three (inclusive) occurrences
h            Itself
(?:lr){0,3}  Zero to three occurrences of the two characters
$            End of string
```

If the zero to three occurrences of `lr` must be saved for future use then modify the RegEx to be `^((?:lr){0,3})h((?:lr){0,3})$`. Then `\1` holds the `lr`s before the `h` and `\2` hold those after it. (Or `$1` and `$2` depending on which RegEx implementation is used).

Comment: I've changed the question. If instead of `lr` there is a huge regexp, then I will have to repeat it twice, based on your solution. It doesn't satisfy me

Comment: @Empty If a RexEx capture is used later in that same RegEx then it looks for exactly the characters that were matched. Thus the RegEx `^(abc)h\1$` will only match the string `abchabc` (ignoring case in all my examples here). The RexEx `^(a+b+c+)h$`  will match `abch` and `aabbcch` and so on. The RexEx `^(a+b+c+)h\1$`  will match `abchabc` and `aabbcchaabbcc`  but it will not match `aabbcchabc` or `abchaabbcc`.

Comment: @Empty As far as I know the only way to make a RegEx such as `^((?:lr){0,3})h((?:lr){0,3})$` not repeat part of itself is to use the string facilities of your language. Thus in C# I could write `string part = "((?:lr){0,3})"; string regex = "^" + part + "h" + part + "$";`.

Comment: I knew this very well. This relates more to the obstacles to solving my problem than to the solution

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about generating a string for the regex. But think about it, will it be fast? The compilation of this regexp will not be entirely optimized. So I need either a compiler that finds repetitions, and this is not always justified, or a regex that has support for the variables that I need. Maybe I'm wrong about the execution speed, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Empty Is it really going to be slow? Donald Knuth is know for saying "[premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256133/discussion-between-empty-and-adrianhhh).